# What all things i need to do to export a Ganglia graph data in json format?

Tags: json, ganglia

I have installed gmetad and it works perfectly fine showing the graphs of the various resources. Now i need to export the json values corrspoding to the graphs for some purpose (appending &json=1 to url). How to get this working. I have read several manuals and blogs. Its all confusing and nothing works. I am using ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest ganglia web. it supports exporting individual graph data into CSV or JSON. just like appending &json=1 to the graph URL from ganglia web. you just need to click a graph, then click the green button with text "json" from the top bar.